# Authentication thought Azure AD in application hosted on IIS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

Is there possibility to authenticate users through Azure Active Directory when my application written in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 is hosted on IIS (not on Azure)?
Use case is to have users stored in Azure AD and while login to my application I would checks users in Azure AD.
I was thinking about custom ApplicationUserStore which would connect Azure AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to authenticate users through Azure Active Directory (AAD) for ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 application.

You could use the **Azure Active Directory Authentication Library** nuget published by Microsoft to manage the AAD authentication in your application.

**Note:** The current stable release of the above nuget does not support ASP.NET 5.

You will need to use the newer pre-release version for ASP.NET 5 support.

Reference: [Active Directory Authentication Library NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - that is what I've been looking for!

Comment: @dawidr, glad to help you!