# IIS Authorization

Tags: azure, iis, azure-active-directory, azure-vm

I have a website in my IIS and within the website there are different folders. So I want to restrict access to these folder so USer A, B and C will have access to folder 1 ([www.example.com/folder1](http://www.example.com/folder1)) and User D will have access to folder 2 ([www.example.com/folder2](http://www.example.com/folder2)). Is this something that can be configured on the IIS server using Azure AD as authentication. Also, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will be accessible to everyone just the folder will have limited access to specific users.

Comment: If you use Azure AD/OpenID for authentication, then its authorization goes through OAuth https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization#authorization . Both are not supported natively by IIS (as IIS URL based authorization only supports classic AD). You have to develop your own IIS extensions if you want better integration.

Comment: @LexLi Would I be able to restrict access to folders using a normal AD?

Comment: @weewoo yes you can. by adding this code in your configuration file: <location path="folder/subfolder">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="DOMAIN\Domain Admins"/>
            <deny users="DOMAIN\Domain Users"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Azure AD authentication will not work at the server level, AAD authentication can be added at the application level, There are [multiple libraries for different languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/) available to integrate your app with [Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization). [Azure AD authentication is essentially built on oAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/about-microsoft-identity-platform) and native support for the same within IIS is not available.

you could refer below link for more detail:

[Authentication thought Azure AD in application hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693881/authentication-thought-azure-ad-in-application-hosted-on-iis)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/11093/windows-iis-integration-with-azure-ad.html